# Custom Text in a href

Tags: javascript, php

Can someone help me how i can manage to support this to work with translation text option.

```html
<a
    href="{{url('account/my-review/delete/'.$value->id)}}" 
    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this review?');"
>
    <i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: #898b8d;"></i>
</a>
```

so i want to replace text Are you sure with text translation like : `{{ trans('plugins/real-estate::dashboard.no_review') }}`

To read my information from my file.
Any ideas how to do it?
Cause if i input it like that it just skip the pop up message and directly delete the record without show message.

Comment: "_Cause if i input it like that..._" Like what? What have you tried to replace the text?

Comment: if i replace the text with the {{ trans it directly skip the pop up message box and delete the record

Comment: Show your efforts in your question.

Comment: Also this should be done with event listeners. `onclick` is very 1998.

Comment: if you can tell me better option if this is 1998 as you mention please provide some better workout, thank you.

Comment: "_should be done with event listeners_" ... that _is_ the better option!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you wrap with single quotes the blade bindings(`{{}}`)? It should work like this:

```
onclick="return confirm('{{ trans('plugins/real-estate::dashboard.no_review') }}');"
```

If not, then probably need to use laravel's `__('plugins/real-estate::dashboard.no_review')`, so then:

```
onclick="return confirm('{{ __('plugins/real-estate::dashboard.no_review') }}');"
```

Comment: If you need to seek clarification from the author, use comments to do so, not answers.

Comment: you are absolute right in both options works if its after (' , even with __(' works tested it shows the text. Thanks.